# Find duplicate data in sheet1 and if it is found in sheet2 then it has to highlight with some specific design(Color)

Tags: vba

```
Sub Compare2sheets()
    Dim ws1 As Workbook, ws2 As Workbook
    Dim s1 As String, s2 As String
    s1 = InputBox("Enter 1st sheet name")
    s2 = InputBox("Enter 2nd sheet name")
    Set ws1 = Sheets("s1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("s2")
    Dim rcount As Long, ccount As Long
    rcount = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    ccount = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    For r = 1 To rcount
        For c = 1 To ccount
            If ws1.Cells(r, c) <> ws2.Cells(r, c) Then
            ws2.Cells(r, c).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
        Next c
    Next r
    Set ws1 = Nothing
    Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Question: I am not able to execute the above code.  How do I execute this code?

Answer (score 0):

ws1 and ws2 are declared as Workbooks, but the should be declared a Worksheets.
Change the first line of your code to:

```
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
```

Furthermore youe have to remove the double quotes when referring to the Worksheets:

```
Set ws1 = Sheets(s1)
Set ws2 = Sheets(s2)
```